# Oracle: LISTAGG excluding first row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that concatenates values for a given id:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT(t.VALUE), ' - ')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE DESC)
  FROM MY_TABLE t
  WHERE t.id=?
  GROUP BY t.id;
```

How can I modify this query to exclude the first (i.e. most recent) value?

- if there are 2 records, only one value should be returned
- if there's only 1 record, then null should be returned
- if all the values are identical, then null should be returned

Comment: what do you mean by the last one.  a list with no elements or not include the row all together?

Comment: Select _unique_ values -> sort by date desc -> concat all except the first.

Comment: As an aside, `UNIQUE` is not a function. It is an optional keyword of the `LISTAGG` function (that is undocumented and a synonym of the documented `DISTINCT` keyword).

Comment: @armandino -- you still didn't answer my question.  If there is only on distinct value do you want a row returned with null or no row returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RANK` analytic function to filter the first row:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT value, ' - ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS value_list
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         created_date,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   MY_TABLE
  WHERE  id = ?
)
WHERE  rnk > 1;
```

*Note: If you are trying to get `UNIQUE` values then the `RANK` (or `DENSE_RANK`) analytic function will filter the latest created date out when there are two-or more-rows tied for the latest created date; if you use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function then you would still get instances of the latest created date when there are ties.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (id, value, created_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B', DATE '2023-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'C', DATE '2023-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B', DATE '2023-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'B', DATE '2023-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, when the bind variable is 1, 2 or 3, the output is:

| VALUE_LIST |
| --- |
| *null* |

When the bind variable is 4, the output is:

| VALUE_LIST |
| --- |
| C - B - A |

And when the bind variable is 5, the output is:

| VALUE_LIST |
| --- |
| A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y1B_HUWZ)

---

#### Update:

Based on the OP's comment, it appears they want to filter values when any row exists with that value and the latest created date. In which case, you can: filter by `id` first; aggregate by value to find the latest date for each value and the maximum date across the entire result set; and then filter to ignore the latest date; and aggregate with `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(value, ' - ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS value_list
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         MAX(created_date) AS created_date,
         MAX(MAX(created_date)) OVER () AS max_created_date
  FROM   MY_TABLE
  WHERE  id = ?
  GROUP BY value
)
WHERE  created_date < max_created_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bY8dBNkS)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, that helps a lot. I modified the dates to be different. The second example (`id = 2`) returns `A`. Can `null` be returned instead if there's only one unique value?

Comment: @armandino The dates were deliberately identical so that you can see it filters out all the latest rows when there are multiple rows tied for the latest. You need to clarify what you expectations are for filtering unique values as #4 has `B` as the latest value but it includes `B` when it is also there for an earlier date.

Comment: I updated the question. The idea is that the returned value shouldn't be the same as the first row. e.g. if all values are the same, then the  query returns `null`.

Comment: @armandino Updated based on what I think your clarified requirements are.

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the right answer

```
WITH numbered AS 
(
  SELECT x.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE DESC) as RN
  FROM MY_TABLE x
)  
SELECT LISTAGG(UNIQUE(t.VALUE), ' - ')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE DESC)
FROM numbered t 
WHERE t.id=? AND RN > 1
GROUP BY t.id;
```

However this won't give you null for items that have only one row.  For that you need to do this:

```
WITH numbered AS 
(
  SELECT x.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE DESC) as RN
  FROM MY_TABLE x
)  
SELECT LISTAGG(UNIQUE(x.VALUE), ' - ')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COALESCE(t.CREATED_DATE,NOW()) DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM MY_TABLE
) X 
LEFT JOIN numbered t ON t.id = X.id AND t.RN > 1
WHERE x.id = ?
GROUP BY x.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a CTE to flag the most recent values and then add a `where` condition to not select it:

```
with my_table_flagged as
(
    select --other values from table
        , row_number() over (partition by t.ID order by t.CREATED_DATE desc) rn
    from my_table t
)
SELECT LISTAGG(UNIQUE(t.VALUE), ' - ')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.CREATED_DATE DESC)
  FROM my_table_flagged t
  WHERE t.id=?
  AND rn <> 1
  GROUP BY t.id;
```